# Anonymized chat messages are now searchable by user

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, privacy

Something appears to have changed recently whereby anonymised messages have become searchable under the user.

For example;
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?user=1640606&q=stackoverflow

This hasn't previously been possible, so I assume this bug has been created by a recent change?

This raises a privacy concern, as I assume there are cases whereby chat messages have been anonymised for a reason, mainly to hide the author.

Comment: Since when can you anonymize chat messages? How does it work?

Comment: @Stormblessed there is an "anonymize messages" moderator tool for chat users, I never used it so I don't know anything more than the name of the tool. I also assume that chat user deletion anonymizes messages just like user deletion on the main sites does

Comment: @MadScientist well in that case the user is not deleted, so the bug is likely in display, they forgot to add some filter to some SQL statement. :)

Comment: This was fixed at some point? I followed the link and can only see one message posted after you asked this question.

Comment: As @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog points out, the only message shown in that search result now is from after the previous messages were anonymized, so this issue appears to have been fixed. As such, I've retagged this post as [status-completed].

Comment: It can take up to five minutes for anonymized messages to be dropped from the search index (or rather, have the user id dropped from the index). Maybe in this case the OP checked immediately after anonymizing?

Comment: @balpha I tried reproducing myself a few days after this was filed and was able to reproduce at the time.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog With definitely more than five minutes between anonymization and search?

Comment: @balpha I followed the link in this post at the time so...yes. I think the most likely cause is that the search indexer wasn't running correctly at the time.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Turns out you're absolutely right. Back then there was indeed an issue with reliable updating of the search index after anonymization. The code that I was looking at was only added as a bug fix in response to this meta post, and we just forgot to update this post.

Comment: (credit to @V2Blast for doing archeology here)